# postgres - set n_distinct to a percentage

Tags: postgresql

As per the [ALTER TABLE documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html#SQL-ALTERTABLE-DESC-SET-ATTRIBUTE-OPTION), a negative n_distinct value behaves like quoted below. Specifically it says

> a value of -0.5 implies that each value appears twice on the average

But please look at my test below. For a value of -0.5, I get an estimate of 2 rows when there are 10.000 rows in the table and I get the same estimate of 2 rows when there are 510.000 rows in the table. Similarly, for a value of -0.001, I get an estimate of 1.000 rows when there are 10.000 rows in the table and I get the same estimate of 1.000 rows when there are 510.000 rows in the table.

```
create table tab(a int);

insert into tab select * from generate_series(1,10000);

analyze tab;
explain select * from tab where a = 5;
-- Correctly estimates 1 row
--Seq Scan on tab  (cost=0.00..170.00 rows=1 width=4)
--  Filter: (a = 5)

alter table tab alter column a set (n_distinct = 20);  

analyze tab;
explain select * from tab where a = 5;
-- Correctly estimates 1000/20 = 500 rows
--Seq Scan on tab  (cost=0.00..170.00 rows=500 width=4)
--  Filter: (a = 5)

alter table tab alter column a set (n_distinct = -0.5); 

analyze tab;
explain select * from tab where a = 5;
--Seq Scan on tab  (cost=0.00..170.00 rows=2 width=4)
--  Filter: (a = 5)

alter table tab alter column a set (n_distinct = -0.1); 

analyze tab;
explain select * from tab where a = 5; 
--Seq Scan on tab  (cost=0.00..170.00 rows=10 width=4)
--  Filter: (a = 5)

alter table tab alter column a set (n_distinct = -0.001); 

analyze tab;
explain select * from tab where a = 5;   
--  Seq Scan on tab  (cost=0.00..170.00 rows=1000 width=4)
--  Filter: (a = 5)

insert into tab select * from generate_series(10001,500000);

alter table tab alter column a set (n_distinct = -0.5); 

analyze tab;
explain select * from tab where a = 5;
--Gather  (cost=1000.00..6889.67 rows=2 width=4)
--  Workers Planned: 1
--  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on tab  (cost=0.00..5889.47 rows=1 width=4)
--        Filter: (a = 5)

alter table tab alter column a set (n_distinct = -0.001); 

analyze tab;
explain select * from tab where a = 5;
--Gather  (cost=1000.00..6989.47 rows=1000 width=4)
--  Workers Planned: 1
--  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on tab  (cost=0.00..5889.47 rows=588 width=4)
--        Filter: (a = 5)
```

**How does that observed behaviour fit the definition? Table size seems to not matter?** The definition says:

> number of distinct nonnull values in the column is linear in the size
> of the table; the exact count is to be computed by multiplying the
> estimated table size by the absolute value of the given number

Full quote from documentation:

> When set to a negative value, which must be greater than or equal to
> -1, ANALYZE will assume that the number of distinct nonnull values in the column is linear in the size of the table; the exact count is to
> be computed by multiplying the estimated table size by the absolute
> value of the given number. For example, a value of -1 implies that all
> values in the column are distinct, while a value of -0.5 implies that
> each value appears twice on the average. This can be useful when the
> size of the table changes over time, since the multiplication by the
> number of rows in the table is not performed until query planning
> time.

Answer (score 0):

It assumes the literal value you are querying for will be present at least once.  If you use -0.5, then it assumes that given it is present once, it will be present twice. With -0.001, it assumes that given it is present once, it will be present 1000 times.

The size of the table doesn't matter in this case, because the assumption it is present at least once will obviate the size of the table.

To see the effect of the size of the table, you would need to query with something like:

```
explain select distinct a from tab;
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, but I fail to follow it. How does table size not matter in my example but in your example with `distinct` it does? In my example, the negative value I use for n_distinct does change the # of rows the planner expects to find, but why does table size not matter when the value is a percentage? So negative values behave the same was as positive values?